# How can I make the tooltips show up correctly in a horizontal table?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

using a horizontal table, I can't seem to make the Bootstrap tooltips to show up correctly:

**DEMO in JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/BWP6t/1/

the header code is

```
<th class="text-center ttip success" title="Day 1 - 06 aug 2013">1544</th>
```

but on hover, the `position:absolute` creates a spacing aside of the hovered element.

Is there a way to make it showing correctly without showing that space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `container` option to append the tooltip to the body it should work correctly.

```
$(".ttip").tooltip({
    container: 'body'   
});
```

Comment: why didn't I thought about the `container`! Arrrghhh it's 2am and I can't think right. Thank you for the answer.